# How to change default namespace in kubernetes' context from default kops command?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kops

I use `kops export kubecfg ${NAME}`  to create a context for `kubectl` , however, I would like to change the default namespace.

I know I can create a namespace in a new context with something like:

`kubectl config set-context my-context --namespace=myNamespace`

But how could I change the default namespace in an already existing context?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that `set-context` is a misnomer and it can be user to modify a context, so the following will do just what is needed to change de default namespace in `kubectl` from `kops` command:

`kubectl config set-context ${NAME} --namespace=myNamespace`